# How to use only face id in androidx.biometric?

Tags: android

In my app I am using biometric authentication with androidx.biometric lib. To check are biometrics available I am using `biometricManager.canAuthenticate()` method. I want to ignore fingerprint and use only face id. I would like to know is there any method to get available biometrics list, or another way to use only face id

Comment: Would you like me to start a bounty on this? Or is it an outdated question?